# Default password for hp c7000 blade servers

Tags: blade-server

Has anybody worked on hp c7000 blade servers before. I have just ordered them and brought them on network. I tried logging in from web browser but I do not have the default password to log in. User guide says default password is provided with the tag supplied with the KVM module but I did not find any such tag.

I am also working with hp customer care but it's taking too much time. So posted here to get some quick help from you guys. Thanks!

Comment: Bear with HP Customer service, they're pretty much the only ones who can help you, I suspect.

Comment: Harsh.  They're people too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

YOu Can find the password on management module interface backside of blade enclosure. remove the IMM module from bay and you can see the password on the top.

Comment: Yes you are right Azim, it is on the back side of IMM module and I found this out after I connected it through hyper-terminal and booted in lost password mode and recovered the password.  HP customer should have known the exact location. Thanks for your help azim!!

Answer (score 0):

This is right. Normally the Password is on the KVM Module for the Server. When you plug in you need the data from the paper on the Module there should be an ip-adress, too. When you use the network you can access over this ip.

Otherway look into your boxes. There should be some Tags(peace of small paper with a barcode) for your servers. It's really important.

I have found [this](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00705292/c00705292.pdf?jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN) in another Forum. Perhaps there, you can get more information.

Comment: Yes Tag should be there, I have searched everything but could not find tag or anything. The link you provided, I have already gone through that and heper terminal is one option. But I do not have null modem cable so now arranging that!!:) Thanks for your help.

Comment: Tom the OA password is also printer on a label on the actual OA too - you have to physically remove it and it may be on the bottom but it's there, not just on the 'flappy' label.

Comment: The referred PDF link is now available here: https://web.archive.org/web/20130203112803/http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00705292/c00705292.pdf